# Replace text or a cell with"'" with an empty cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

To use some of the data analysis functions in Excel, every cell must have a number or be empty.  I want to replace cells with the word "Blank" and cells that look blank but have a "'" in them with an empty cell. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this.  Any help?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119614/return-empty-cell-from-formula-in-excel

Answer (score 0):

For cells that look blank but have a `'` character, do this:

- Select the range of cells
- Select **Data > Text to Columns**
- In the Convert Text to Columns Wizard, select **Delimited > Next**
- Uncheck all delimiters and select **Next**
- Select **Finish**.

For cells with `Blank` use the replace-text function
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
to replace the string by nothing.

Comment: If you need to do this to an abundance of columns (in my case, 1000+), it may be worth it to just copy the data to a .CSV temporarily, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

For cells with "Blank", you can press Ctrl and H to replace it with space.

For cells with "'", you can copy all cells to text file, then you can copy them back to Excel workbook.